# Unexplained behavior with script tags being moved in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've found some strange behavior trying to reproduce something else and I thought it was interesting.

My jsbin example is [here](http://jsbin.com/obuney/3)

The core code:

```
  <div id="diag">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      if(x==undefined){
        var x=1;
      }else{
        x=x+1;
      }
      alert(x);
      });
    </script>
  </div>
```

(at the bottom of the page)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#diag').dialog();
});
```

`$.dialog` I know will move this script in the DOM, so it is expected that it will be executed twice. However, the results are different than I would expect.

I expected for it to say 1 and then 2. However, it says 1 and then 1 again. How is that even possible? This behavior is consistent across Firefox5, Chrome, and IE8

Comment: `x` is not a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

the scope of x is inside that function, it is redefined on the 2nd call

Answer (score 0):

```
var x;
$(document).ready(function(){

    if(x==undefined)
        x=1;
    else
        x=x+1;

    alert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the "x" variable is the block for the if statement.  This means that x is defined here:

```
var x=1;
```

And then is destroyed and returns to undefined here:

```
}else{
```

What you want to do is make sure that x is defined in a larger scope.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = 1;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if(x == undefined){
      x = 1;
    } else {
      x = x + 1;
    }
    alert(x);
  });
</script>
```